Page is reloading when user navigates back to it, but only in safari and not in chrome
I have a store page (missingnewyork.com/base-store) and on page load, there is a css animation that makes the products slide from the last product to the first product. If the user scrolls through the list of products, then clicks on a product to take them to a product page, then clicks the back arrow, I need the state of the store page to be exactly the same as it was before the user navigated away to a product page. This is currently how it works in desktop chrome and it is perfect. But in desktop safari (or in chrome or safari on mobile devices) if the user scrolls through the store page, clicks on a product page, then clicks back, it RELOADS the entire store page... meaning the animation is played again, thus the user loses the scrolling position that they were left at.
I'm not looking to conditionally control the state of the animation, I'm trying to implement a cache based solution. So when the user is on the store page, and then clicks on a product page, at this exact point, I need the server to cache the current state of the store page. So that when the user navigates back to the store page, it doesn’t try to reload the store page. This is already how it seems to be working in desktop chrome and it is literally perfect. But it seems safari / mobile browsers are handling caching differently?
I’m trying to set up my .htaccess file to ensure the caching works like I need it to, but I cannot get it to work. This is my new .htaccess file -
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^missingnewyork.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.missingnewyork.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]

# Set environment variable to cache page when navigating away from any page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www\.missingnewyork\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ - [E=set_cache:1]

# Set caching headers for page if set_cache environment variable is set
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=3600" env=set_cache
    Header set Expires "Wed, 01 Jan 2025 00:00:00 GMT" env=set_cache
</IfModule>

To reiterate, I am trying to get the server to cache the state of the page when the user navigates to a new page, and then when the user clicks the back button, I need the server to use the previously cached page in order to retain the last state it was at instead of reloading the entire page.
When I upload this new .htaccess file to my server, I still have the same issue. It does not seem to appropriately cache my store page when the user clicks on a link. Does anyone know where I’m going wrong?
